# Program doesn't enter if statement in Julia

Tags: julia

There is this block of code in my program that I simplified here, while the initial value of previoF is false the program doesn't print "s1" and only prints "s0".

I tried looking at it in various ways, and I don't get what is wrong with the code.
Could it be that I am not writing the if statement the right way somehow ?

```
previoF = false

for f in filter(x -> endswith(x, "VMSource.vm"), readdir())

open(f,"a") do file



    for ln in eachline(open(f))

        if (previoF==false)
            if(contains(ln,"Add"))
                println("s1")
            end
            previoF=true

        else
            if(contains(ln,"Add"))
                println("s0")
            end

            previoF=false
        end

    end
end
end
```

Comment: Just wondering... Why do you have 2 `open` statements? Also, do "Add" lines fall on even lines in the files? You could insert more print statements in your `if` blocks to trace execution.

Comment: The "if" construct looks fine. It might help if you post a sample of the file you are accessing.

Comment: Can you tell us the version of Julia you are using? (There are *a lot* of breaking changes between the 0.x versions, and 1.0 hasn't been released yet).